# httpd won't start after editing etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, certbot

I am following this below guide to install free SSL on AWS linux server using Certbot.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#letsencrypt

I have followed the instructions under "Prepare to install" till STEP 2 in the above guide. But I can't able to restart **httpd** after editing etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file as mentioned in the guide.

**See the error I got below:**

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-34 ~]$ sudo systemctl restart httpd
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**Result of systemctl status httpd.service**

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-34 ~]$ systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-03-31 06:22:10 UTC; 6min ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 5145 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5145 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Reading configuration..."

Mar 31 06:22:10 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Sta...
Mar 31 06:22:10 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal httpd[5145]: AH...
Mar 31 06:22:10 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal httpd[5145]: In...
Mar 31 06:22:10 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: htt...
Mar 31 06:22:10 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Fai...
Mar 31 06:22:10 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Uni...
Mar 31 06:22:10 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: htt...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

**Result of journalctl -xe**

```
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-34 ~]$ journalctl -xe
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Mar 31 06:30:02 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starte
-- Subject: Unit session-86.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-86.scope has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Mar 31 06:30:02 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal CROND[5164]: (root
Mar 31 06:30:02 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Remove
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down.
Mar 31 06:30:51 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal dhclient[2878]: XM
Mar 31 06:32:41 ip-172-31-40-34.eu-central-1.compute.internal dhclient[2878]: XM

[1]+  Stopped                 journalctl -xe
```

**Output of the apachectl configtest**

```
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-34 httpd]$ apachectl configtest
AH00526: Syntax error on line 48 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command '\xcb', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: `Invalid command '\xcb'` - what did you try to resolve that? And why is this question tagged with EC2, [tag:ssl-certificate], and [tag:certbot] - how are these related if a test of Apache's configuration already shows an error?

Comment: I want to restart the httpd to Install and run Certbot for Let's Encrypt SSL setup on AWS EC2 instance as mentioned in the guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#letsencrypt

Comment: So, why not fix that error that was given by running `configtest`?

Comment: Please see the content of line 48 below:  
</VirtualHost>

I didn't find any error on it

Comment: You haven't shared the configuration file itself. Also, did you check for any special characters that could be invisible to a common file editor?